# .NET ReportViewer Error - Only when running from Server, not from Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, webforms, reportviewer

I am getting client rendering error for one of my report. I am getting this error only when running from our Testing Server, the report runs fine in my development environment (i.e from my local machine Visual Studio IDE).

Below are the details of the error. I am totally stuck as I am not able to make anything out of the stack trace. What should be my next step?

**ASPX Code:**

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptvwReport" runat="server" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)">
<LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\ChartReport.rdlc"></LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

**ASPX.CS Code:**

```
ReportDataSource rdsReport = new ReportDataSource();
rdsReport.Value = myDataList;//List<Data>
rdsReport.Name = "DS";
rptvwReport.LocalReport.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath) + @"/Reports/ChartReport.rdlc";
rptvwReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdsReport);
rptvwReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

**Note:** I am using Visual Studio 2010 & SQL Server 2008. For testing purpose I am using same database for both Development & Testing environment.

> ***Error Message:** An error occurred during client rendering.*
>
> ***Inner Exception:** Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*
>
> ***StackTrace:** at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalHtmlRenderer.Render(NameValueCollection deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, ReportControlSession reportControlSession, CreateAndRegisterStream streamCallback, String& scrollScript, String& pageStyle) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControlSession.RenderReportHTML4(NameValueCollection deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& scrollScript, String& pageStyle) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControl.RenderReport(ReportControlSession session, String viewerInstanceIdentifier, PageCountMode pageCountMode, Int32 pageNumber, InteractivityPostBackMode interactivityMode, SearchState searchState, String replacementRoot, String hyperlinkTarget, ScrollTarget scrollTarget, String alertMessage, DeviceInfoCollection initialDeviceInfos, String browserMode, Boolean sizeToContent) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportArea.RenderReport(ReportControlSession session, String viewerInstanceIdentifier, PageCountMode pageCountMode, Int32 pageNumber, InteractivityPostBackMode interactivityMode, SearchState searchState, String replacementRoot, String hyperlinkTarget, ScrollTarget scrollTarget, String alertMessage, DeviceInfoCollection initialDeviceInfos, String browserMode, Boolean sizeToContent) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.RenderReport(Boolean updateDocMap) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)*

Comment: The next step is to find the relevant code that is causing the problem, and post it here. That stack trace is too generic to be of any help.

Comment: @gunr2171 - Added the code. The problem I am facing here is my development environment is not throwing any error.

Comment: does your bin file contain the same files on both machines?

and are you running IIS on both of them?

Comment: Bin folder contains same files, in testing server I am running IIS 7 and for development I am using the Visual Studio 2010 IDE directly (view in browser)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that in your BIN folder you have the following: -

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll

Your project will probably only have a reference to Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll; if you need to locate them, they will be in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer

I had a similar issue with an intranet app that used the ReportViewer, same versions of VS and SQL as you, and I had to include the additional DLL's in the publication package.

Comment: I checked, the DLL's are there